# Acumatica Bug - Send Email with Signature results losing your message in newest version of chrome

Tags: acumatica

Since the newest version of chrome came out, whenever you try to send an email in Acumatica results in your message being lost if you have an email signature. (Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Steps to reproduce

```
1) Ensure you have a signature on your user profile (just some simple text is fine)
2) Go to any screen that has activities tab (ex: BAccount)
3) Click "Add Email"
4) Type in a subject and put some text above your signature
5) Click save (or send) and your message will disappear
```

This issue happens in 17R2 as well as the newly released 18R2. Tested using the Sales Demo.

Does anyone have a fix for this yet? Or can anyone else confirm they also have this issue.

UPDATE:

Tracked the issue to this in CREmailActivityMaint

```
  protected virtual void CRSMEmail_Body_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        var signature = GetSignature(true);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature))
            e.NewValue = Tools.AppendToHtmlBody(e.NewValue as string, "<br />" + signature);
    }
```

It's causing the HTML to be invalid which then causes the editor to be broken which makes any text you add to get deleted. We have added a temporary hack until we hear back from Acumatica. It's not idea, but we weren't sure how else to get the data fixed and we have a lot of people sending blank emails.

```
 protected void CRSMEmail_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        CRSMEmail row = (CRSMEmail)e.Row;
        {                
            if (null != row.Body)
            {                   
                row.Body = row.Body.Replace("<br /><HTML>", "<HTML>");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue in the Business Account screen Activities tab using Acumatica 2018 R1 and Microsoft Edge browser. It doesn't seem to be browser related.

Without the signature block I can't reproduce the issue so it does seem to be related to the signature.

I couldn't reproduce it in the Cases screen Activities though.

Your 5 steps test procedure along with version information is sufficient to reproduce the issue. It does look like a bug in the base Acumatica product. If you have access to an Acumatica partner I would recommend you work with him to report the issue to Acumatica engineering team.

Comment: Thanks @HB_ACUMATICA we sent an email to our partner but we also tracked down the issue and implemented a temporary hack. I updated the original post.